# force overwrite in windows when copying a file

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell-3.0, overwrite, robocopy

I want to copy the file whether it's newer/older/same from `$lpath` to `$bpath`.

What am I doing wrong? None of these methods overwrite the existing file. They only copy the file if the file does not exist.

PowerShell:

```psh
$lpath = 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Outlook Files\myemail@gmail.com.pst'
$fname = ($lpath.Split('\')[-1], (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy")) -Join "."
$bpath = -Join ('D:\OutlookBackup\', $fname)

Copy-Item -Path $lpath -Destination $bpath -Recurse -Force
```

robocopy:

```psh
$llpath = 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Outlook Files'
$bbpath = 'D:\OutlookBackup'

robocopy $llpath $bbpath 'myemail@gmail.com.pst' /IS
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? The PowerShell method works fine for me (I am using PSv4 on Win8.1). Are you able to manually name a file that, and copy it over if it already exists in the destination? Perhaps it's locked by something like AV and can't be over-written or something.

Comment: no error on powershell or robocopy. the only way the file copies is if the file is not there already or if i copy the file with a different name. i have full access (minus special permissions) to the directory where the .pst file is and the file aswell. i tried using xcopy but no luck.